# Creating tables with Do command

Tags: list-manipulation

Why when I perform this code why am I not producing tables called roots[j], each containing 3 elements which are the roots of the equation?

When I type roots[0] for example I get roots[0] as answer instead of 3 different roots.

```
Do[roots[a] = z/.NSolve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z]], {a, -15, 15, 0.1}];
```

Comment: Is there something missing in the code you copied?  This doesn't even run.

Comment: To get any answers at all, you have to write e.g. `root[0.]`, not `root[0]`. The reason is that since you increment by `0.1`, `a` will be a real number and not an integer. If you do it, you should get three values for `z`, that's what I get. Maybe you need to restart your kernel.

Comment: Thanks. I re-ran the kernel and the code now works! I still don't get why you need the full stop after an input since roots[2] is the same as roots[2.]. Isn't 2 the same as 2.?

Comment: If I enter roots[2.4] I still get not solutions printed though?

Comment: You can not assign to index variables inside a Table like this. These are effectively like definition of function you are making and not assignments. But you can still access the values stored in roots outside the Do loop by looking at `DownValues@roots`

Comment: The syntax for `Table` is wrong here. You need to specify a second argument to tell `Table` how to iterate. A single argument table like `Table[expr]` does evaluate, but it just returns `expr` and doesn't do anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Using `NSolve` for numerical solutions, filtering for `Reals`.

```
Clear[roots]

Do[roots[a] = NSolve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z, Reals], {a, -15, 15, 0.1}]

ListPlot[Table[Map[{a, #} &, z /. roots[a]], {a, -15, 15, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

Evaluate `InputForm[DownValues[roots]]` to see the results.  Note the floating point numbers, e.g. `roots[2.400000000000002]`, which explains why `roots[2.4]` does not return any values.

You could use `Round` to overcome this problem.

```
Clear[roots]

Do[roots[Round[a, 0.1]] = NSolve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z, Reals], {a, -15, 15, 0.1}]

roots[2.4]
```

> {{z -> -3.07116}, {z -> -0.849142}, {z -> 0.920299}}

Alternatively, use rational numbers in the iterator, with `N` to numericise.

```
Clear[roots]

Do[roots[N[a]] = NSolve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z, Reals], {a, -15, 15, 1/10}]

ListPlot[Table[Map[{a, #} &, z /. roots[N[a]]], {a, -15, 15, 1/10}]]

roots[2.4]
```

> {{z -> -3.07116}, {z -> -0.849142}, {z -> 0.920299}}

Comment: I think this works:

Comment: ReSolutions2 = Table[{a, Re[z]} /. Solve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z], {a, -15, 15, 0.1}];
    ImSolutions2 = Table[{a, Im[z]} /. Solve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z], {a, -15, 15, 0.1}];

Comment: Note: I do not want to plot the Real solutions but the Real part of the complex/real solutions

Comment: OK. You should still use `NSolve` for numerical solutions.  `Solve` is for symbolic solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done in a shorter way, no need for the `Table`

```
Clear[roots]
Do[roots[a] = z /. Solve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z], {a, -15, 15, 0.1}]
roots[-1.]
```

Comment: No result for `roots[2.4]` though.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen That is a feature, not a bug :)